# Is it safe to boil sweetened condensed milk in the can to make dulce de leche?

Tags: food-safety

Is it? I am talking about metal poisoning not the explosion risk, will the can leak dangerous metals into the dulce de leche product when boiled or is it safe to eat? (I am hoping it is because it is very convenient but if its not what to do safety first)

Comment: I have done it several times, since that is what my recipe for banoffee pie calls for to make the toffee. I am however not a chemist :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe. Nearly all if not all canned foods sold commercially  have been processed in retorts (industrial pressure cookers) to kill microrganisms
The metal from the can is not going to leach into the food contained in it

Comment: It's perfectly safe as long as the can doesn't explode.  You can avoid this by ensuring that the can stays completely submerged the whole time, or by opening the can and leaving the open end exposed to the air.  Based on a quick scan of Google search results, the closed can method seems to be a lot more popular.

Comment: While many (if not most) commercially canned goods are pressure cooked, sweetened condensed milk apparently isn't. See, e.g., http://dairyprocessinghandbook.com/chapter/condensed-milk

Comment: @derobert but is it still safe?

Comment: @MoeEpo I don't know. I'd guess yes (I doubt any dangerous metals are used in the can, and none melt at so low a temperature). I'd be more worried about plastics/etc. used in it, though I suspect they're fine at boiling, but have no actual evidence to point to.

Comment: Many cans are lined with plastic or epoxy.
https://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/can-ripper/

https://www.mnn.com/food/healthy-eating/blogs/which-food-companies-dont-use-bpa-lined-cans

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT COOK in containers made for packaging. They contain an epoxy coating that will leach BPA into your food when heated to cooking temperatures.
This is especially true with the recent craze of cooking sweetened condensed milk in an Instapot (pressure cooker). Inside a pressure cooker water boils at 250 degrees. Everything is hotter than on top of the stove and, even more BPA will leach into your caramelized milk.

Comment: Do you have any support for your claim here?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Your answer makes some claims about food safety; consider linking those claims to authoritative sources.

Comment: I don't believe it's a "recent craze". My mother has been cooking condensed milk in a pressure cooker since the 80's.

Comment: It's likely that condensed milk (depending on the brand/packager) is sealed in a can that has a gold enamel lining. You do realize that many foods, as part of the commercial canning process, are essentially cooked in the can? Even more go into the container hot and are held at temperature while being sealed, etc.

Comment: @gnicko did you read the other posts? Derobert's comment points out that sweetened condensed milk is not heated in the can. So we don't know if the cans for condensed milk are heat-stable or not.

Comment: @rumtscho Yes, the cans are heat-stable. The same coatings are used for multiple types of foods. BPA leaches into food while the can sits on the shelf without any additional heating. I'm not sure that milk products typically use internal coatings that include BPA, but even if they do, a few batches of dulce de leche shouldn't be a problem. The OP was concerned with metal poisoning, which is even more of a "snowball's chance" kind of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t mean this in a snarky way, but what’s wrong with just dumping it into a pan, double boiler maybe? I know you have then created one more dirty dish but that eliminates the possibility of any off tastes or metallic tang in the milk.

Comment: Yes with suitable pan this is the best choice with that I agree with you.